# Easy-rules: set rule name in a POJO using a contructor

Tags: java, easy-rules

I have the following Rule

```
@Rule
@Slf4j
public class ModuleRule{

  private Content content;
  private String baseDir;


  @Condition
  public boolean when(Facts facts) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    content = facts.get("content");
    baseDir = facts.get("base_dir");

    Method getModule = content.getClass().getMethod("get"+name);
    return (boolean) getModule.invoke(content);
  }

  @Action
  public void then(@Fact("toInclude") List<Template> selectedTemplates) throws IOException, TemplateGenUtilsException {
    log.info("Adding module:" + name);
    final String moduleTemplatesPath = String.format("%s/%s", baseDir, name);
    selectedTemplates.addAll(FileUtils.replacePath(moduleTemplatesPath, FileUtils.loadTemplates(name), content.getDOMAIN(), content.getAPP_NAME()));
  }
}
```

Which is instantiated in a the following way:

```
 @Bean
  public Rules rules() {
    Rules rules = new Rules();

    templatesConfig.getModules().stream() .   //Modules is a list of String
        .map(ModuleRule::new)
        .forEach(rules::register);

    return rules;
  }
```

The code won't work as after the first registration, the other rules have the same name and therefore won't be registered. 
Therefore, here is my question: is there a way to create a new rule and set its name at runtime?

I have also tried to extend BasicRules, the problem here is that when the engine fires, the rule is not evaluated. Here is the code:

```
@Slf4j
public class ModuleRule extends BasicRule{


  private Content content;
  private String templatesBaseDir;


  public ModuleRule(String name) {
    super(name);
  }

  @Condition
  public boolean when(Facts facts) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    content = facts.get("content");
    templatesBaseDir = facts.get("base_dir");

    Method getModule = content.getClass().getMethod("get"+name);
    return (boolean) getModule.invoke(content);
  }

  @Action
  public void then(@Fact("toInclude") List<Template> selectedTemplates) throws IOException, TemplateGenUtilsException {
    log.info("Adding module:" + name);
    final String moduleTemplatesPath = String.format("%s/%s", templatesBaseDir, name);
    selectedTemplates.addAll(FileUtils.replacePath(moduleTemplatesPath, FileUtils.loadTemplates(name), content.getDOMAIN(), content.getAPP_NAME()));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Silly error: the BasicRule extension works BUT you need to override the execute and evaluate methods and not use the annotation.

Everything works now!